# Ubuntu Sublime Text 3 SublimeLinter jshint not working

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I just can't get jshint working on my sublime text3..
I already install SublimeLinter package and sublimelinter-jshint..
I also already install node.js and instal jshint modules with this command

```
sudo npm install -g jshint
```

but it's just not working.
here is my sublime setting file

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": false,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "save only",
        "linters": {
            "jshint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            },
            "php": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [
                "/usr/local/bin/jshint"
            ],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "php_paths": {
            "linux": [
                "/usr/bin/php"
            ],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
            "magicpython": "python",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

I wonder anyone have a solution.